# Can't import the named export 'ChangeDetectionStrategy' from non EcmaScript module in Angular 8

Tags: angular, pagination, angular8

I wanted to put pagination on my Angular 8 project with ngx-pagination.

But as soon as I import the module in app.module.ts I get this error:

"Can't import the named export 'ChangeDetectionStrategy' from non EcmaScript module".

Googling I discovered that it could be a problem related to my version of Angular, only that unfortunately I can not update Angular to a major version, the site is for a customer who wants this version.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I have not found a solution to this problem, but I hope it will be useful to whoever will read.  As a working alternative I used ng-pagination.